# How many committees of $6$ people can be formed from $10$ married couples if no married couples serve on the committee?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have a question I didn’t manage to solve.

There are $10$ couples (one man and one women in each) and they are going to make a committee of $6$ people. The committee can’t contain a married couple.

a) How many combinations if you are to choose $3$ women and $3$ men?

b) $3$ women and $3$ men, all with different tasks?

In b) is it $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5$?, there are $10$ ways to choose the first woman, $9$ for the second woman, $8$ for the third women and $7$ for the first man....

Comment: What did you try?  Show your attempts.

Comment: I did try something on b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How many committees of six people can be formed if you are to choose three women and three men given that the committee cannot contain a married couple?

**Strategy**

1. Choose which three of the ten women will serve on the committee.
2. Since no married couples may serve on the committee, the three men who are married to one of those women have now been eliminated from consideration. Choose which three of the remaining seven men will serve on the committee.

> There are $\binom{10}{3}$ ways to choose which three of the ten women will serve on the committee and $\binom{7}{3}$ ways to choose which three of the remaining seven men will serve on the committee.  Hence, there are $$\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{3}$$ committees which may be formed from $10$ married opposite-sex couples consisting of three women and three men which do not contain a married couple.

> How many committees of six people can be formed if you are to choose three women and three men given that the committee cannot contain a married couple and each person on the committee is to complete a different task.

**Strategy**

1. Choose who will serve on the committee, which is what we did above.
2. Assign a different task to each of the six people selected to serve on the committee.

> We found above that there are $\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{3}$ ways to select who will serve on the committee.  The six members who are selected to serve on the committee can be assigned six different tasks in $6!$ ways.  Hence, there are $$\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{3}6!$$ ways to select a committee consisting of three women and three men from $10$ married opposite-sex couples if no married couple serves on the committee and each committee member is assigned a different task to perform.

What is wrong with your attempt?

You have assigned a woman to perform the first task, one of the remaining women to perform the second task, one of the remaining women to perform the third task, one of the men to perform the fourth task, one of the remaining men to  perform the fifth task, and one of the remaining men to perform the sixth task.  However, any person selected to serve on the committee may perform any of the tasks, which is why you should first select who will serve on the committee, then assign tasks to the committee members.